# Get all apps a user has from Google API

Tags: google-api

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all the users apps (that is apps published by the user *NOT* apps downloaded by the user).

Which API should I be looking at? I'm also interested in getting data about the apps uploaded.

Something like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Goodgame+Studios
But as a api call.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no official API to do that.

You may look for some third-party APIs like http://www.playstoreapi.com but I don't know if it is enough for you.